# Find all methods used in Java class

Tags: java

Hello I am curious about possibility of finding **all** methods that are **used** in a Java class.
So far I tried stuff like `java.lang.reflect.Method` including:

`className.class.getMethods();` - it's not giving me expected result.

**Expected Result:**

I want to get all methods that are used in class like : `Java.lang.Object.equals()`

Comment: That's not possible. You'd need to parse the source files to determine whether a method is used or not, even then you're not guaranteed to catch all calls (for example calling methods with reflection).

Comment: I think this may answer your question: [Answered in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31204747/5436073)

Comment: @Thoma: the answer you linked to answers a very different question, namely which methods *exist* in a given class.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Kayaman: You don't need the source, the bytecode of the class contains the method calls (again with the caveat of reflection, though). There should be some static analysis tool that can come up with this information.

Comment: @Thilo yea, didn't mean the literal source code. Rather that it's impossible to do with runtime reflection and it's not fool-proof even if doing source/bytecode analysis.